# Why can't I take the reference of the result of try! with &?

Tags: rust

It's not exactly an idiomatic MVCE, but it should illustrate the question. Given the following code:

```
fn foo() -> Result<String, i32> {
    return Ok("world".to_string());
}

fn bar() -> Result<String, i32> {
    let mut value = String::new();
    value.push_str(&try!(foo())); // this line here

    return Ok("Hello ".to_string() + &value);
}

fn main() {
    match bar() {
        Ok(message) => println!("{}", message),
        _ => return,
    }
}
```

Rust returns the error:

> `<std macros>:3:43: 3:46` error: mismatched types:
>   expected `str`,
>   found `collections::string::String`
>   (expected `str`,
>   found struct `collections::string::String`) [E0308]
>   `<std macros>:3 $ crate:: result:: Result:: Ok ( val ) => val , $ crate:: result:: Result::`
>   `<std macros>:1:1: 6:48` note: in expansion of `try!`
>   `<std macros>:3:43: 3:46` help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
>   error: aborting due to previous error

If I instead capture the result of `try!` and separately apply `&` to the result, it works (and prints out `Hello world`):

```
fn foo() -> Result<String, i32> {
    return Ok("world".to_string());
}

fn bar() -> Result<String, i32> {
    let mut value = String::new();
    let foo_result = try!(foo()); // capture the result of try!
    value.push_str(&foo_result); // now use the result with &

    return Ok("Hello ".to_string() + &value);
}

fn main() {
    match bar() {
        Ok(message) => println!("{}", message),
        _ => return,
    }
}
```

Why does `let foo_result = try!(foo()); value.push_str(&foo_result);` work but `value.push_str(&try!(foo()));` not? From my naive perspective, they appear to be equivalent, so I'm not sure what key part of Rust I'm not understanding.

Comment: It's a very good MVCE. Not an answer, but still a little something I usually do: http://is.gd/PZKWz0

Comment: You can resolve even with value.push_str(&&try!(foo()));

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that the compiler handles the coercion of a block differently. `try!()` is expanded to a `match` block, and the compiler fails to auto-deref it. Your problem can be abbreviated like below:

```
fn f(_: &str) {}

fn main() {
    let x = "Akemi Homura".to_owned();

    f(&x); // OK
    f(&(x)); // OK
    f(&{x}); // Error
}
```

I think this is a bug of the compiler. As stated in [RFC 401](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0401-coercions.md), the compiler should be able to coerce blocks with appropriate types.

> blocks, if a block has type `U`, then the last expression in the block (if it
>   is not semicolon-terminated) is a coercion site to `U`. This includes blocks
>   which are part of control flow statements, such as `if`/`else`, if the block
>   has a known type.

As a workaround, I recommend you to convert `String` into `&str` directly, using `&*try()` or `&try()[..]`. Both have the same meaning, although I prefer the former slightly.

I opened an issue to track this. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26978